# 6-pin SMD identification - top marking B7 AP

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

I am trying to repair a Garmin Echo fishfinder after moisture got into it, I have replaced the op amp but it seems the 6-pin device above it is also faulty. The trouble is I can't identify what it is. I'm guessing it's some kind of optocoupler to protect the digital processing from spikes from the transducer signals. It only has top marking B7 AP and a dot near the bottom left pin.

Can anyone suggest what it might be?

[image: photo of PCB]

I'm sorry, I seem to have transgressed the rules, I saw that other people had asked about identifying components and thought I'd do the same.
Thanks to those who replied to the question, I'll try and look it up with the information you gave.
Apologies again.

Comment: FWIW, it looks like a [NC7SB3157](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NC7SB3157-D.PDF), the GND and VCC pin looks the same, and the package marking seems nearly the same.

Comment: Can you provide an in-focus picture of the 6-Pin device? Can you probe out the circuit and draw out what its connected to? Pin 2 looks like it's connected to the ground plane

Comment: All small SMD parts have a code. You can look the code up in an SMD codebook to find what the part is (http://www.marsport.org.uk/smd/mainframe.htm).

Comment: Why on earth is this closed as a _repair_ question when it's clearly just an identification question?

Comment: Dear new user Ken, you have more grace and manners than some on this group.  I do hope that you will not be driven away by the over zealous self moderation that occurs here.  There are thousands of helpful folk here and only a few that fear the system will fall apart if any amount of latitude or flexibility is shown in the guidelines.   Also remember even if some come across as negative they are often a fountain of information if a question is presented in a way that they are comfortable with.